# Alternative function for alternative user inputs in c

Tags: c

The user is supposed to write inputs such as " A  Smith  Renault " (we're making a car race- leaderboard sort of thing) .

My program is supposed to react to the first letter ( e.g. "A" from the example above) because that letter gives the program the right instructions what to with the rest of the information.

Questions:
 What function should I use to identify the letter? Or should I split up the user input somehow?

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: You can store the string in array and then can use switch case on zeroth index of the array. E.g. `switch(arr[0]) { case 'A': call_func(); break; }`
Something like this.

Comment: Do you even know what an `if` statement is?

Comment: It can be done in several ways. The way you read the input, is important for the subsequent parsing. So show us how you intend to read the user input. Also it is important whether you know that it is always the first character.

Comment: @Peter Who, me?

Comment: @GauravPathak My question was directed to the OP.   But if the shoe fits ....

Comment: @Peter ohh, okay!! Actually, I just gave an example because I thought there is going to be more input from user, so OP can add more cases in the switch case logic and should not be limited to just 'A'.

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/kvssh7)

Answer (score 0):

If user must write all that in one input, just user strtok() function. For example, in your input "A Smith Renault" if you do:

```
 char str[80] = "A Smith Renault";
 const char s[2] = " ";
 char *token;
 token = strtok(str, s);
```

In token variable you will get the a letter A.